# Github Action DotNetCore sln and project in same folder

Tags: .net-core, yaml, github-actions

```
name: .NET Core
```

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Setup .NET Core
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
  with:
    dotnet-version: 3.1.101
- name: Install dependencies
  run: dotnet restore
- name: Build
  run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
- name: Test
  run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
```

this my yml code .
it showing error MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

### [error]Process completed with exit code 1.

in `dotnet restore` step because the sln in the project folder. how to solve this problem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just define path to the directory that has solution or project file. Assuming that project file location is `src/MyProject/MyProject.csproj`, then `Install dependencies` step should be:

```yaml
- name: Install dependencies
  run: dotnet restore
  working-directory: src/MyProject
```

Answer (score 5):

Specify the solution name

```
- name: Build with dotnet
  run: dotnet build Document.Approval.sln --configuration Release

- name: dotnet publish
  run: dotnet publish Document.Approval.sln -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

Comment: You don't need to do this if the solution is in the root directory of the source code and it throws an error if it's not since it looks for  Document.Approval.sln only in the root directory and not subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use "defaults" to set it for all tasks as follows:

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: scripts
```

Source: https://github.community/t/use-working-directory-for-entire-job/16747/16